# image not showing using wp functions

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I want to create an "image" edit button. Here is the code I have tried but it output a broken image:

```
echo "<td><a href='" . 
        admin_url('admin.php?page=get_employee_update&id=' . $value->id) .
        "'><img src='<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/i_edit.png'/>" . 
        "</a></td>";
```

I have also tried template_directory function but it didn't work. Can you guys help me what's wrong with that code? I'm a beginner in wordpress it just happen that I have encounter this kind of problem in my custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You're using php tags inside 'echo'.

Try this:

```
echo "<td><a href='" . 
    admin_url('admin.php?page=get_employee_update&id=' . $value->id) .
    "'><img src='". get_template_directory_uri() . "/img/i_edit.png'/>" . 
    "</a></td>";
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it outputs an error.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' 

I've tried :
    echo "<td><a href='".admin_url('admin.php?page=get_employee_update&id=' . $value->id)."'><img src='". get_template_directory_uri();"/img/i_edit.png'/>"."</a></td>";

the code above doesnt throw an error but still the image is not seen or broken.

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra semicolon after get_template_directory_uri(). I've edited my answer, please use that. Your code has the semicolon too, replace it with a '.'. A '.' is used to concatenate strings